# Tokenize words into syllables (gujarati characters) for Gujarati

Tags: java, nltk, tokenize, nlp

I am trying to tokenize `Gujarati` (an `Indian` language) word into characters.

Example :
વાનર is word then I want list of characters like [વા, ન, ર]

I tried `java.text.BreakIterator` with `Gujarati` `locale` but it did not work. Though it works perfectly for `Hindi`.

Here is code :

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Language{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "વાનર";
        Locale gujarati = new Locale("gu","IN");
        BreakIterator breaker = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance(gujarati);
        breaker.setText(text);
        int start = breaker.first();
        for (int end = breaker.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = breaker.next()) {
            System.out.println(text.substring(start,end));
        }    
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
વ
ા
ન
ર
```

Is there any library that can do it correctly?
I am fine with languages other than `Java`

Comment: I never tried with those special characters, but wouldn't it work the basic way, using `String#charAt(int index)`?

Comment: @jhamon I guess that doesn't work, the string has length of 4 which would lead to the same output

Comment: Example with expected output is different from the actual code and output. Plus I don't know Gujarati . Could you explain what is wrong with the current ouput?

Comment: @jhamon.. I corrected example. I am expecting output as  [વા, ન, ર] (list with size 3) and output given by code is [વ, ા, ન, ર] (list with size 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a small python function to convert `Gujarati` words into list of `Syllables`. My code is inspired by this Github repo [libindic/syllabalizer](https://github.com/libindic/syllabalizer).

**Code:**

```
def syllabify_gu(text):
        signs = [u'\u0abe',
                u'\u0abf',
                u'\u0ac0', 
                u'\u0ac1', 
                u'\u0ac2', 
                u'\u0ac3', 
                u'\u0ac4', 
                u'\u0ac5',
                u'\u0ac7', 
                u'\u0ac8', 
                u'\u0ac9',
                u'\u0acb',
                u'\u0acc',
                u'\u0a81',
                u'\u0a82',
                u'\u0a83',
                u'\u0acd'] 
        limiters = ['\"', '\'', '`', '!', ';', ', ', '?', '.']

        lst_chars = []
        for char in text:
            if char in limiters:
                lst_chars.append(char)
            elif char in signs:
                lst_chars[-1] = lst_chars[-1] + char
            else:
                try:
                    if char == u'\u0ab0' and len(lst_chars) > 0 and lst_chars[-1][-1] == u'\u0acd' and lst_chars[-1][-2] == u'\u0aa4': 
                        lst_chars[-1] = lst_chars[-1] + char
                    else:
                        lst_chars.append(char)
                except IndexError:
                    lst_chars.append(char)

        return lst_chars

syllabify_gu("સંગીત એ એવું પવિત્ર ઝરણું છે, જેનાં વહેતા તરંગોથી અંતરનાં તાર રણઝણી ઉઠે છે.")
```

**Output:**

```
['સં',
 'ગી',
 'ત',
 ' ',
 'એ',
 ' ',
 'એ',
 'વું',
 ' ',
 'પ',
 'વિ',
 'ત્ર',
 ' ',
 'ઝ',
 'ર',
 'ણું',
 ' ',
 'છે',
 ',',
 ' ',
 'જે',
 'નાં',
 ' ',
 'વ',
 'હે',
 'તા',
 ' ',
 'ત',
 'રં',
 'ગો',
 'થી',
 ' ',
 'અં',
 'ત',
 'ર',
 'નાં',
 ' ',
 'તા',
 'ર',
 ' ',
 'ર',
 'ણ',
 'ઝ',
 'ણી',
 ' ',
 'ઉ',
 'ઠે',
 ' ',
 'છે',
 '.']
```

Find Unicode for Gujarati characters [here](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0A80.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this library gives exact solution that you want but I wrote a library called MgntUtils and published it as an Open Source available as Maven artifact on Maven central 
 (see [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar)) as well as on [github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) There is a utility there that converts any String to unicode sequence and vise-versa. All you will have to do is:

```
String codes = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("Hello world");
```

And it will return String `"\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064"`

The same would work for any String in any language including special characters. There is a method that does the decoding back:

```
decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(String unicodeSequence)
```

Here is the [javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html) link. you can easily break  unicode sequences string into single unicodes and store them like this or even convert them back as separate Strings and get your characters. Here is the link to the article [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/) that explains about the library

Comment: converting to Unicode will not work as વાનર in Gujarati gets converted to 4 Unicode characters but actually it is 3 characters or syllables in Gujarati.

Comment: I don't know the Gujarati language, but what I see that Symbols 'વ' and ' ા' are two different letters. If their combination creates a single syllable I don't know (but  I trust you do) but they are two distinct characters as far as encoding is concerned: codes '\u0ab5' '\u0abe'. So the result you were getting in your code are correct as far as splitting the string into separate letters. As for your desired result, either there should be some language specific support or you will need to search for letter combinations that from language standpoint are a single syllable and treat them as one

Comment: I am looking for language-specific support only.